# Get list of items from a string in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I have the following string which I need to parse with Ruby:

```
Long description text which could have multiple returns.

This is the final line of the description.
~
1. This is step 1

2. And this is step 2

3. There could be an infinite number of steps

4. But this is the last step
```

I'd like to split out everything before the list of steps into a string, and then have an array of steps.

In Objective-C, I'd do this using ranges and a `while` loop until it can't find anymore steps.

I'm thinking there may be something smarter in Ruby, but I haven't been able to find anything.

Comment: You cannot have an infinite number of steps in a string although you can have an arbitrary number of steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do using [`split`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-split) and [`scan`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-scan):

```
string = <<EOS
Long description text which could have multiple returns.
This is the final line of the description.
~
1. This is step 1
2. And this is step 2
3. There could be an infinite number of steps
4. But this is the last step
EOS

description, list_text = string.split('~')
list = list_text.scan(/^\d+.*$/)

puts description
# Long description text which could have multiple returns.
# This is the final line of the description.

p list
# ["1. This is step 1", "2. And this is step 2", 
#  "3. There could be an infinite number of steps", 
#  "4. But this is the last step"]
```

Comment: The `.scan(/^\d+.*$/)` is exactly what I was after. Thanks!

Comment: @toro2k: I tried something like this which did not work `a=[]; a[1] = (a=s.scan(/(?<!=~).*/m)[0].split("~"))[1].split("\n")`. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: @Bala I don't know... I guess it is due to the assignment `a[1] = ( a = ...`. If you ask me, the actual problem is that you have tried to squeeze all that code in just one line. :-)